# shell script to test condition on passed string

Tags: bash, shell-script

condition 
string either start with upper or lower alphabets or underscore
for example _abc or xyz or Abc

string may contain digits after first character 
like _f9  or f10 or car20  or top10cars

string should never contain special characters like ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) + - =

here my tiny script

```
if [[ $1 =~ ^[A-Za-z_]+$ ]]; then
  echo it matches
else
  echo does_not match
fi
```

when i pass argument like only & or * or ( , script don't work , sometimes cursor never comes backs , i need to press ctrl+c

```
for example    ./script.sh (abc 
               ./script.sh &&
               ./script.sh &abc
```

whats wrong with script

Comment: edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting.

In the script, use `"$1"` rather than just `$1`.

On the command line, use

```
./script '*(ontehu'
```

instead of

```
./script *(ontehu
```

---

- `./script.sh (abc` This is a syntax error in the shell grammar.
- `./script.sh &&` This makes the shell think there is a conditional AND on the command line and it expects something on the right hand side of the `&&` operator.
- `./script.sh &abc` This is two commands: `./script` started as a background process (with `&`), and the command `abc`.

In all these cases, the argument should be quoted (single quoted, ideally, unless you need the shell to insert the value of a shell variable, in which case it should be double quoted).

---

Your script:

```
if [[ $1 =~ ^[A-Za-z_]+$ ]]; then
  echo it matches
else
  echo does_not match
fi
```

Quote `$1`:

```
if [[ "$1" =~ ^[A-Za-z_]+$ ]]; then
  echo it matches
else
  echo does_not match
fi
```

Allow digits in the tail end of the value:

```
if [[ "$1" =~ ^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]+$ ]]; then
  echo it matches
else
  echo does_not match
fi
```

Do proper reporting of errors (this is extra):

```
if [[ "$1" =~ ^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]+$ ]]; then
  printf '"%s" is a valid variable name\n' "$1"
else
  printf '"%s" is not a proper variable name\n' "$1" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because these are reserved characters.

& means run command in the background

* resolves to all files/dirs in the actual directory, which are then passed as arguments

() is used for command order preference or function declarations

If you want such a characters in the string, put it in quotes " " or ' '